# Two way bind checkbox to boolean property in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Is there a way to bind a bool to a checkbox ischecked property, and automatically update this property if the UI changes?

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsFilterOn}" />

public bool IsFilterOn    {
    get;
    set;
}
```

What changes do I need to make to this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the binding in to two way mode:-

```
 <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsFilterOn, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

If you want the UI to update if other code changes the property on the object you should also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your object.  You will then have full bi-lateral observation on the property.